# EF6 (6.1.3/ net45) Logging feature does not seem to work

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, oracle, logging, entity-framework-6

When I attempt to run the line:
    MyDBContext.Database.Log = Console.Write 
The compiler smiles and tells me I don't know what I am doing...

The app won't compile because of the line and the error on that line is:
Overload resolution failed because no accessible Write accepts this number of arguments.

That makes sense. 'Console.Write' returns nothing and I am setting it equal to a System.Action(Of String)

This just seems kind of half baked.
I tried numerous ways to fix it including  delegates, and some of the other 'new possibilities' moving this off the Context is supposed to offer but still no dice.
What am I missing? Is it something that was changed at the last minute?

I have two large edmx files (one connects to SQL Server and the other to Oracle) in the solution and all of that is working great.
Here are my version numbers if that can help.
EntityFramework 6.0.0.0   (folder is ...\EntityFramework.6.1.3\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll)
EntityFramework.SqlServer 6.0.0.0  (folder is ...\EntityFramework.6.1.3\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll)
Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework 6.121.2.0

I have a tool I created that lets me paste the output of the L2S 'mycontext.log' into it and it then parses it and creates SSMS ready SQL with variables... it has been incredibly useful. This has been one of my favorite features of L2S.
Please help me understand why this isn't working.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This technique works for me:

```
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        SetIStateInfo();
#if DEBUG
        Database.Log = s => Debug.WriteLine(s);
#endif
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
```

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mpeder/archive/2014/06/16/how-to-see-the-actual-sql-query-generated-by-entity-framework.aspx

Comment: Thanks, Steve. I hadn't thought of using an override.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the answer was to research the [Action(T) Delegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8(v=vs.110).aspx) which showed me how to do it.

```
#If DEBUG Then
      myctx.Database.Log = AddressOf Console.Write
#End If
```

Just needed the AddressOf and I was back in business.